# Show that $f^*:B \to A$ is a function iff $f$ is bijective as follows.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Let $f: A \to B$. Let $f^*$ be the inverse relation, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
f^* = \{(y,x) \in B \times A \mid f(x)=y \}.
\end{equation*}
Show that $f^*:B \to $ is a function iff $f$ is bijective.

**Attempt:**
Right now, I'm only have a problem for the right direction, but only on the injectivity proof.

Let $f^*$ is a function from $B$ to $A$.
Let $x,z \in A$ and take some $y \in B$ such that $f(x) = f(z) = y$. Then,
$(y,x),(y,z) \in f^*$. Since $f^*$ is a function, then we must have $x=z$. Hence, $f$ is injective.

Is the injective proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine, but you could also do this, which is a tad more elegant in my humble opinion:

$\implies$direction: Suppose that the inverse relation $f^* \subset  B  \times A$ is in fact a function $f^*: B \to A$. By definition, that means $f$ is invertible. But $f$ is invertible iff $f$ is bijective. Therefore $f$ is bijective. (See Theorem 1 in these notes from Northwestern: [https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/300/notes/functions.pdf](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/%7Escanez/courses/300/notes/functions.pdf))

Comment: okay noted. thanks!

Comment: @user795084 You're welcome, and if you like my answer, please feel free to select it as the official answer.

Comment: Can you help me answer my question before this?

Comment: @user795084 Sure, do you mean in the other direction?

Comment: yes! the question about uniqueness of inverse

Comment: To prove that the inverse of $f$ is unique, suppose that $f$ has two inverses, $g$ and $h$. We need to show that $g=h$. Since $g$ is the inverse of $f,$ that means $ g \circ f=id_A$ and $ f \circ g=id_B.$ Likewise, $h \circ f=id_A $ and $f \circ h = id_B.$ Then $g=g \circ id_B=g \circ (f \circ h)= (g \circ f) \circ h= id_A \circ h=h.$

Comment: N1. But, why you answer here,not there?